# PHP Array Issue 'Illegal string offset'

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to create a navigation menu from a MySQL database.I have this code that takes the results array of a mysql query ($row) and puts them in ($item). When I process each of the $items, I am getting these warnings:

> **Warning:** Illegal string offset 'parent_id' in C:\xampp\htdocs\bootstrap\includes\navigation.php on line 52
>   Warning: Illegal string offset 'parent_id' in C:\xampp\htdocs\bootstrap\includes\navigation.php on line 52
>   **Warning:** Illegal string offset 'page' in C:\xampp\htdocs\bootstrap\includes\navigation.php on line 53

I have tried to change `$item['id']`, `$item['page']`, and `$item['parent_id']` to `$item[0]`, `$item[1]`, and `$item[2]` respectively and this did not work either. I have roamed Google trying to see what else to do. This code is borrowed from a solution that is working here:

http://www.websitesdevelopments.com/blog/post/dynamic-multilevel-css-drop-down-menu-using-css-php-and-mysql

But I don't know why it isn't working for me.

```
<?php
include("includes/database.php");

try {
    // read all pages from the database     
    $query = "SELECT * FROM pages";     

    // prepare query statement
    $stmt = $con->prepare( $query );

    // execute query
    $stmt->execute();

    //count the number of pages
    $num = $stmt->rowCount();

    //put results array into variable
    $rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

}catch(PDOException $e) { 
    //something wrong with query/datbase connection
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>

 <?php
     $items = $rows;
     $id = '';
     print_r($items);

    foreach($items as $item){
      if($item['parent_id'] == 0){
          echo "<li><a href='#'>".$item['page']."</a>";
          $id = $item['id'];
          sub($items, $id);
          echo "</li>";
      }
    }
     echo "</ul>";

    function sub($items, $id){
        echo "<li class='dropdown'>";
        echo "<a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>Portfolio <b class='caret'></b></a>";
        echo "<ul class='dropdown-menu'>";
        foreach($items as $item){
            if($item['parent_id'] == $id){
                echo "<li><a href='?page=".$item['page']."'>".$item['page']."</a>";
                sub($items, $item['id']);
                echo "</li>";
            }
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }

     ?>
```

Comment: How do you obtain ``$rows``? What you are trying to do would only work, if ``$rows`` is an associative array (not with numeric indices), but with property names, like ``parent_id``. There is a difference between using ``mysql_fetch_array`` and ``mysql_fetch_assoc``.

Comment: @Guido Kitzing, thanks for your prompt comment. I have added the mysql porition.

Comment: @OrionEllis and when you print_r($items) you get assoc array with key names 'parent_id', 'page' and 'id'?

Comment: Thanks @Guido Kitzing. I have changed to fetchall and all is good - thanks for the clue that lead me to this. Code is now: $rows = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

Comment: @OrionEllis - if solved through comment or by yourself, please post self-answer and accept it so correctly marked in SO. Give credit to idea source and include change you made to make it work please